# When using javascript to dynamically and a textarea, how can I render it as a tinyMCE editor (in wordpress)?

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, tinymce

I have a plugin that allows the user to dynamically add sections that need to have the tinyMCE editor in them. The jQuery clones a `div` and places it into a container. One of the input boxes is a textarea set up like so:

`<textarea name="sectionContent_1" id="sectionContent_1"></textarea>`

I need to replace the textarea with the tinyMCE editor.

I've looked at:

[How to load wp_editor() through AJAX/jQuery](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/51776/how-to-load-wp-editor-through-ajax-jquery)
and
[use wordpress wp_editor in dynamic/ajax html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21519322/use-wordpress-wp-editor-in-dynamic-ajax-html)

Neither of these seem to work for us

I've tried this inside the trigger that calls to add the textarea section:

```
$(this).parent().find('.sectionOptions').html(ctHolder);

var textAreaID = 'sectionContent_'+sectionID;

tinyMCE.execCommand('mceRemoveEditor', true, textAreaID);
tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddControl', false, textAreaID);
```

In this, I'm adding the cloned data (ctHolder) to the `.sectionOptions` setting the textarea's ID, resetting the editor on the ID, then adding control to the ID... this doesn't work but seems to be most commons suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

This did the trick:

```
var textAreaID = 'sectionContent_'+sectionID;           $(this).parent().find('.sectionOptions').html(ctHolder).ready(function(){
    tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddEditor', false, textAreaID); 
});
```

Wordpress 3.9 is using tinyMCE 4.x so "mceAddControl" was changed to "mceAddEditor". Also, I placed the call inside a ready function so jquery wouldn't run tinyMCE until after it loaded the textarea on the dom.