# wp_editor() in content that was loaded with ajax

Tags: ajax, wordpress, tinymce, editor

I try to use `wp_editor()` in content that was loaded with ajax, but none of the required files and some other configuration script not loaded :

The structure of ajax is something like this:

```
function get_test_page(){
   include( TEMPLATEPATH . '/page.php' );
   die( main() );
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_get_test_page', 'get_test_page' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_get_test_page', 'get_test_page' );
```

page.php :

```
function main(){
    wp_editor('','unique_id');
}
```

Editor is loaded but needed files is not loaded.

- `http://.../wp-includes/js/tinymce/wp-tinymce.php`
- `http://.../wp-includes/js/tinymce/skins/lightgray/skin.min.css`
- `http://.../wp-admin/load-scripts.php?c=1&amp;load%5B%5D=...mce-view,imgareaselect,image-edit,word-count,editor,quicktags,wplink,thick..`
- `http://.../wp-includes/js/tinymce/langs/{}.js`
- `...`

Some related post but doesn't help me :

[use wordpress wp_editor in dynamic/ajax html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21519322/use-wordpress-wp-editor-in-dynamic-ajax-html/24324677#24324677)

[How to load wp_editor() through AJAX/jQuery](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/51776/how-to-load-wp-editor-through-ajax-jquery)

Comment: This is like a rabbit warren this task. I've spent days trying to do the same thing always settling for a compromise.

Comment: Is there any alternative solution to do this?

Answer (score 2):

**Solution**:

Add `wp_editor()` in somewhere that works perfectly and hide it.

```
<div class="hidden-editor-container" style="display:none;">
    <?php wp_editor( '', 'editor' ); ?>
</div>
```

after that assign editor contents to the global JS variable.

```
EDITOR = $('.hidden-editor-container').contents();
```

Finally when the ajax page is loaded append editor contents

```
$('.editor').append( EDITOR );

tinymce.execCommand( 'mceRemoveEditor', false, 'editor' );
tinymce.execCommand( 'mceAddEditor', false, 'editor' );
```

Comment: Many months later, and after two days of messing around this is also pretty much all I can come up with.

Comment: Sorry for asking an old Thread/Post, but `tinymce` is not defined and i can't find similar variables like `tinyMCE` or other... can you say me where the editor-API is presented?

Comment: @AdrianPreuss Make sure you defined **tinymce** before above solution.     wp_enqueue_script('tinymce') or wp_editor()

Comment: its already defined because the editor is placed on the edit.php which had already the editor :)

Comment: @AdrianPreuss I have no idea, I used this code in front end and this worked correctly many times, Maybe its related to your jQuery  :-)