# Load Wordpress Editor Via Ajax Plugin

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress

I have researched several similar questions on stackoverflow about this topic that already have answers.

Some of the answers don't seem to fully work and some are just over my head.

I have been reading and reworking my code for over a week so I though I would try asking again with more detail than the other questions had.

I've written a very simple WordPress plugin that's only purpose in life is to load a fully functional editor via ajax.

Here is a screencast of this plugin working (with errors):
http://screencast.com/t/eyrTdbUy

I think that if my question can be answered it will help a lot of people.

Here is exactly what the plugin does.

1. It loads my custom page template instead of the theme template. In this template there is a editor created with the wp_editor function (to load the required files) and a link to add a new editor.
2. When you click the "add editor" link a new editor is created using the wp_editor function via ajax then initialized with javascript and new link is added to add another.

This only works if a user is logged in.

I wouldn't advise installing this on your active website because it will take over your pages. This plugin is for example only so it should only be installed on tester sites.

**Here's the problems...**

1. The first instance of the ajax loaded editor works but there is the following errors when you click the tabs to switch back and forth from visual to text
   "TypeError: e is undefined"
   "TypeError: c is undefined"

The "TypeError: e is undefined" also happens when the first new editor is loaded.

1. After the first instance is loaded another editor cannot be added.

So my question is... What is wrong with my code?

The plugin is made up of 4 files.

**File 1 is the plugin file "load_editor.php" (it just includes the functions):**

```
    include('functions.php');
```

**File 2 is the functions file "functions.php":**

```
<?
// load custom editor template 
function load_editor_template( $template )
{
    $template = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'template.php';

    return $template;
}

add_filter( 'template_include', 'load_editor_template' );

// load javascript 
function load_editor_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'load_editor', plugins_url() . '/load_editor/js/load_editor.js', array(), '', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery');
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_editor_scripts' );

// create new editor
function load_editor_new_editor() {
    $id      = $_POST['id'];
    $number  = $_POST['number'];
    $next    = $number + 1;
    $full_id = $id.$number;

    echo "<h1>Editor $number</h1>";

    $content = '<p>This is example content.</p>';
    wp_editor($content, $full_id, array('textarea_rows' => 3));

    // initiate new editor
    echo "<script>
tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddEditor', true, $full_id);
tinyMCE.init(tinyMCEPreInit.mceInit[$full_id]);
</script>";

    // create "add new" text
    echo "<div><a onclick=\"load_new_editor('editor', $next);\" href='javascript:void(0);'>Click here</a> to add another editor</div>";

    die();
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_load_editor_new_editor', 'load_editor_new_editor' );
```

**File 3 is the template file "template.php" :**

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Load Editor</title>
<?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>

<body>
<? wp_editor('Ecample content', 'id',  array('textarea_rows' => 3)); ?>

<div id="add"><a onClick="load_new_editor('editor', 1);" href="javascript:void(0);">Click here</a> to add an editor</div>
<div id="editor_container">
<!-- Editors will load here -->
</div>

<script>
<?
echo 'ajaxurl = "'.admin_url('admin-ajax.php').'";';
?>
</script>
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

And file 4 is the javascript file "load_editor.js":

```
function load_new_editor(id, number){
    // remove click to add
    jQuery('#add').remove();

    var fullId = id + number;

    var data = {
        'action': 'load_editor_new_editor',
        'number': number,
        'id': id
    };

    jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {

        //add new editor
        jQuery('#editor_container').append(response);

    });
}
```

I've also put it on github here:
[enter link description here](https://github.com/ccbgs/load_editor)

Thank you so much for any help that you can give. I've been trying to get this to work for so long it's frying my brain. I even hired a programmer via elance and he was unable to get as far as I did.

Comment: Check [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/51776/how-to-load-wp-editor-through-ajax-jquery) and the linked questions.

Comment: Thanks brasofilo. That's one of the ones that got me this far. The answer by Dale Sattler is where I got the code to re instantiate.

I had the quicktags code in an earlier version but it was causing more errors for me.

The answer by shahar seems like another way to initiate it and I tried it but it didn't seemed to work as well as the previous answer.

The one meantioned by bueltge (T5 AJAX Editor) was one of the ones that was over my head and seemed overcomplicated to me. I think maybe I'm just not experienced enough to understand it.

Comment: Yep, it is complicated. But there's something interesting here: https://gist.github.com/toscho/8515113#file-t5-ajax-editor-php-L82 - Try adding `_WP_Editors::enqueue_scripts(); print_footer_scripts(); _WP_Editors::editor_js();` after *wp_editor* located on *template.php*

Comment: Tried adding that and got the same result as far as the ajax loading goes but it gave my 1st editor (the one without ajax) double quicktags. Screenshot: http://screencast.com/t/ACIgnbBi31

Comment: I guess it won't do much, but maybe play with the settings: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.9/src/wp-includes/class-wp-editor.php#L38

Comment: I added that code in my load_editor_new_editor() and got some interesting results. It's still broken but maybe if I play with it a bit I can figure something out.  Do you mean alter the actual wordpress files?

Comment: Oh, no, those are the settings that you can pass to `wp_editor`, just for reference

Comment: Possible duplicate of [use wordpress wp\_editor in dynamic/ajax html](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21519322/use-wordpress-wp-editor-in-dynamic-ajax-html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the best I can come up with and I think it is good enough for me.

Everything is working except the quicktags and I can live without them.

**I removed the javascript from funtions.php**

```
<?
// load custom editor template 
function load_editor_template( $template )
{
    $template = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'template.php';

    return $template;
}

add_filter( 'template_include', 'load_editor_template' );

// load javascript 
function load_editor_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'load_editor', plugins_url() . '/load_editor/js/load_editor.js', array(), '', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery');
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_editor_scripts' );

// create new editor
function load_editor_new_editor() {
    $id      = $_POST['id'];
    $number  = $_POST['number'];
    $next    = $number + 1;
    $full_id = $id.$number;

    echo "<h1>Editor $number</h1>";

    $content = '<p>This is example content.</p>';
    wp_editor($content, $full_id, array('textarea_rows' => 3));

    // create "add new" text
    echo "<div id='add'><a onclick=\"load_new_editor('editor', $next);\" href='javascript:void(0);'>Click here</a> to add another editor</div>";

    die();
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_load_editor_new_editor', 'load_editor_new_editor' );
```

**Then I changed the following on load_editor.js**

1. Added the quicktags function to get the tabs to work without error
2. Called tinymce.init with the settings that WordPress uses

I think that's it.

```
// JavaScript Document

function load_new_editor(id, number){
    // remove click to add
    jQuery('#add').remove();

    var fullId = id + number;

    var data = {
        'action': 'load_editor_new_editor',
        'number': number,
        'id': id
    };

    jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {

        //add new editor
        jQuery('#editor_container').append(response);

        // this is need for the tabs to work
        quicktags({id : fullId});

        // use wordpress settings
        tinymce.init({
        selector: fullId,

        theme:"modern",
        skin:"lightgray",
        language:"en",
        formats:{
                        alignleft: [
                            {selector: 'p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,td,th,div,ul,ol,li', styles: {textAlign:'left'}},
                            {selector: 'img,table,dl.wp-caption', classes: 'alignleft'}
                        ],
                        aligncenter: [
                            {selector: 'p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,td,th,div,ul,ol,li', styles: {textAlign:'center'}},
                            {selector: 'img,table,dl.wp-caption', classes: 'aligncenter'}
                        ],
                        alignright: [
                            {selector: 'p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,td,th,div,ul,ol,li', styles: {textAlign:'right'}},
                            {selector: 'img,table,dl.wp-caption', classes: 'alignright'}
                        ],
                        strikethrough: {inline: 'del'}
                    },
                    relative_urls:false,
                    remove_script_host:false,
                    convert_urls:false,
                    browser_spellcheck:true,
                    fix_list_elements:true,
                    entities:"38,amp,60,lt,62,gt",
                    entity_encoding:"raw",
                    keep_styles:false,
                    paste_webkit_styles:"font-weight font-style color",
                    preview_styles:"font-family font-size font-weight font-style text-decoration text-transform",
                    wpeditimage_disable_captions:false,
                    wpeditimage_html5_captions:true,
                    plugins:"charmap,hr,media,paste,tabfocus,textcolor,fullscreen,wordpress,wpeditimage,wpgallery,wplink,wpdialogs,wpview",
                    selector:"#" + fullId,
                    resize:"vertical",
                    menubar:false,
                    wpautop:true,
                    indent:false,
                    toolbar1:"bold,italic,strikethrough,bullist,numlist,blockquote,hr,alignleft,aligncenter,alignright,link,unlink,wp_more,spellchecker,fullscreen,wp_adv",toolbar2:"formatselect,underline,alignjustify,forecolor,pastetext,removeformat,charmap,outdent,indent,undo,redo,wp_help",
                    toolbar3:"",
                    toolbar4:"",
                    tabfocus_elements:":prev,:next",
                    body_class:"id post-type-post post-status-publish post-format-standard",

});


        // this is needed for the editor to initiate
        tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddEditor', false, fullId); 

    });
}
```

Here is a screencast of it working.
http://screencast.com/t/Psd9IVVY

If anyone knows how to get the quicktags to show, I would love to know.

Also, if you spot something wrong with my code let me know.

I have updated the github if you want to download it here:
https://github.com/ccbgs/load_editor

Answer (score 0):

( Answer found here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/51776/how-to-load-wp-editor-through-ajax-jquery/192132 )

1) **in functions.php**,add:

```
add_action('init','my_wpEditOUPUTT'); function my_wpEditOUPUTT(){
    if (isset($_POST['Give_me_editorrr'])){
        wp_editor( '' , 'txtrID_'.$_POST['myNumber'], $settings = array( 'editor_class'=>'my_class',     'textarea_name'=>'named_'. $_POST['myNumber'],  'tinymce'=>true , 'media_buttons' => true , 'teeny' => false,));
        exit;   
    }
}
```

2) inside dashboard HTML page:

```
<div id="MyPlace"></div> <a href="javascript:myLoad();">Click to load</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
startNumber = 1;
function myLoad(){ alert('wait 1 sec');
    startNumber ++;
    jQuery.post('./index.php', '&Give_me_editorrr=1&myNumber='+startNumber ,
        function(data,status){ 
            if (status == "success") {  
                document.getElementById('MyPlace').innerHTML += data; alert("Inserted!");   
                tinymce.init({ selector: 'txtrID_'+startNumber, theme:'modern',  skin:'lightgray'}); tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddEditor', false, 'txtrID_'+startNumber);
            }
    });
}
</script>
```